# Empty TextBox1.Text is giving me an error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, .net-1.1, asp.net-1.1

I'm getting the following error message on my webform:

```
Cast from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid.
```

I'm assuming it's because of this line (but my assumption could be incorrect):

```
command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("col3", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8)).Value = some_date_parameter
```

Which is in a function:

```
Function ProcessAction(ByVal col1 As Integer, ByVal col2 As String, ByVal col3 As Date, ByVal col4 As Integer, ByVal col5 As String) as something

    '...
    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@col1", SqlDbType.Int, 4)).Value = col1
    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@col2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)).Value = col2
    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@col3", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8)).Value = col3
    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@col4", SqlDbType.Int, 4)).Value = col4
    command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@col5", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)).Value = col5

    '...

    Return something

End Function
```

Which is called via a button:

```
Sub ButtonClick(ByVal Source As Object, ByVal E As EventArgs)

    '...

    structRecord = ProcessAction(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text)

    '...

End Sub
```

Where `structRecord` is:

```
Public Structure structRecord
    Public col1 As Integer
    Public col2 As String
    Public col3 As Date
    Public col4 As Integer
    Public col5 As String
End Structure
```

The actual error gets shown on this line at runtime which is in the `ButtonClick`:

```
structRecord = ProcessAction(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, TextBox4.Text, TextBox5.Text)
```

How can this problem be corrected?  I basically want to allow the user to continue with the rest of the webapp, even if `TextBox3.Text` is left empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you'll test your inputs to ensure they are within a valid or acceptable range.

In the case of a date you'll want to verify that the value will convert to a date and if so, pass that as a parameter.  If it's not a valid date then you can pass a null value to the query.

The query should be smart enough to accept a date or null; however, without that query I can't help you.

Comment: So you think the error is being triggered because of the query, instead of the `Struct` which is expecting a `Date` instead of a `String` for `col3`?

Comment: @oshirowanen:  No.  I'm suggesting you need to do one of two things.  Either change ProcessAction to accept all strings and within it do the validation OR do the correct validation and conversions prior to calling ProcessAction.  Either way, you need to test and do the conversion instead of relying on implicit conversion when you know it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the dateTime.TryParse method to validate the string that your passing in is a valid date/time value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx